# UserWarning: Implicit dimension choice for log_softmax has been deprecated

Tags: python-3.x, macos, deep-learning, pytorch, opennmt

I´m using Mac OS el capitán and I am trying to follow the [quick start tutorial for OpenNMT pytorch](http://opennmt.net/OpenNMT-py/quickstart) version.  In the training step I get the following warning message:

```
OpenNMT-py/onmt/modules/GlobalAttention.py:177: UserWarning: Implicit dimension choice for softmax has been deprecated. Change the call to include dim=X as an argument. 

align_vectors = self.sm(align.view(batch*targetL, sourceL))
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py:67: UserWarning: Implicit dimension choice for log_softmax has been deprecated. Change the call to include dim=X as an argument.
  input = module(input)
```

Step 1: Preprocess data (works as expected)

```
python preprocess.py -train_src data/src-train.txt -train_tgt data/tgt-train.txt -valid_src data/src-val.txt -valid_tgt data/tgt-val.txt -save_data data/demo
```

Step 2: Train model (produces the warning message)

```
python train.py -data data/demo -save_model demo-model
```

Has anyone come across this warning or have any pointers to solve it?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/3238) applies here.

Comment: I think the warning doesn´t stop execution, it just takes a long time for each epoch:

Comment: I got this output recently, right after the warning:                                   
      Epoch  1,    50/  157; acc:   4.21; ppl: 167145.54;  37 src tok/s;  36 tgt tok/s;   2049 s elapsed
Epoch  1,   100/  157; acc:   5.52; ppl: 8718.19;  37 src tok/s;  37 tgt tok/s;   3901 s elapsed

Answer (score 16):

It is almost always you will need the last dimension when you compute the cross-entropy so your line may look like:

```
torch.nn.functional.log_softmax(x, -1)
```

Answer (score 9):

From the warning it's pretty clear that you have to explicitly mention the dimension since implicit dimension choice for softmax has been deprecated.

In my case, I'm using `log_softmax`and I've changed below line of code to include dimension.

```
torch.nn.functional.log_softmax(x) # This throws warning.
```

is changed to

```
torch.nn.functional.log_softmax(x, dim = 1) # This doesn't throw warning.
```